# Series approximation to $\frac{1}{1-(1+x)^{-n}}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, power-series, laurent-series, geometric-series, linear-approximation

I'm attempting to find a series approximation to:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-(1+x)^{-n}}$$

where $n\in\mathbb{N^+}$ and is a constant, and $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $0<x<1$.

Using [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=taylor%20series%201%2F%281-%281%2Bx%29%5E-n%29), I noted the first order approximation is:

$$f(x)\approx\frac{1}{nx} + \frac{n+1}{2n}$$

With this goal post in mind, I went about trying to find the first order approximation for myself. The original formula has a singularity at $x=0$, so I figured I can't use the Taylor series formula directly. Instead, with the geometric series formula I found the following:

$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{1}{(1+x)^{in}} $$

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Is there a trick I'm missing?

Looking around for a hint on how to proceed, I noticed that $f(x)$ has some similarities to mortgage monthly payments formula:

$$C(r)=\frac{r(1+r)^nP}{(1+r)^n-1}$$

where $P$ is the initial load size (principal), $r$ is the interest rate per month and $n$ is the number of payments (months). I found similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1233859/approximation-of-monthly-payment-using-taylor-expansion) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2647675/taylor-series-expansion-for-p-0-r-1%E2%88%921r%E2%88%92n-1), but it's still not clear to me what the initial steps are for finding the first order approximation given by Wolfram Alpha.

Any help would be much appreciated, even if it's just the first few steps towards the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Sage gives the first few terms as $-\frac{{\left(n^{4} - 20 \, n^{2} + 19\right)} x^{3}}{720 \, n} - \frac{{\left(n^{2} - 1\right)} x^{2}}{24 \, n} + \frac{{\left(n^{2} - 1\right)} x}{12 \, n} + \frac{n + 1}{2 \, n} + \frac{1}{n x} + \cdots$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any positive integer $n$,
$$\eqalign{f(x) &= \frac{1}{1 - (1+x)^{-n}} = \frac{(1+x)^n}{(1+x)^n - 1}\cr
&= \frac{(1+x)^n}{\displaystyle\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} ((x + 1 - e^{2\pi i j/n}) }}$$
This is a rational function with limit $1$ as $x \to \infty$ and simple poles
at $e^{2\pi i j/n}-1$ for $j = 0$ to $n-1$, i.e. $\omega- 1$ for the $n$'th roots of unity $\omega$.  Thus it can be written as
$$ \eqalign{f(x) &= 1 + \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \frac{c_j}{x + 1 - e^{2\pi i j/n}}\cr
&= 1 + \frac{c_0}{x}- \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} c_j \sum_{k=0}^\infty  (-1+e^{2\pi i j/n})^{-1-k} x^k}$$
for appropriate constants $c_j$.

Comment: I suspect my complex maths has atrophied as I'm not sure I completely follow. Do you care to expand on: $(1+x)^n - 1 = \displaystyle\prod_{j=0}^{n-1} ((x + 1 - e^{2\pi i j/n})$? How do you also determine the "appropriate constants" such that you can obtain the approximation?

Comment: For any monic polynomial of degree $n$, $p(z) = \prod_{k=1}^n (z-r_k)$ where $r_k$ are the roots of $p(z)$ (counted with multiplicity).  The roots of $z^n - 1$ are the $n$'th roots of unity, namely $e^{2\pi i j/n}$ for $j = 0 \ldots n-1$. $c_j$ is the residue of $f(x)$ at the root $x = e^{2\pi i j/n} - 1$.

Comment: Thanks - I can see where you're going. I definitely need to review my complex mathematics; it's been a while.

Answer (score 2):

Start by multiplying both numerator and denominator by $(1+x)^n$:
$$f(x)=\frac{1}{1-(1+x)^{-n}}=\frac{(1+x)^n}{(1+x)^n-1}$$
Now let's use binomial expansion $$(1+x)^n=1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2x^2+...$$
This yields
$$f(x)=\frac{1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2x^2+...}{nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2x^2+...}\\=\frac1{nx}\frac{1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2x^2+...}{1+\frac{n-1}2x+...}$$
We can now use $$\frac1{1+\frac{n-1}2x+...}\approx1-\frac{n-1}2x$$
This yields $$f(x)\approx\frac1{nx}\left(1+nx+\frac{n(n-1)}2x^2+...\right)\left(1-\frac{n-1}2x\right)\\\approx\frac1{nx}\left(1+nx-\frac{n-1}2x\right)\\=\frac1{nx}\left(1+\frac{n+1}2x\right)=\frac1{nx}+\frac{n+1}{2n}$$
Note that at my last approximation I've dropped terms in $x^2$. If I want to keep those, I need one more term in an earlier expression.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate on how you determined the following approximation: $$\frac1{1+\frac{n-1}2x+...}\approx1-\frac{n-1}2x$$

Comment: You want the denominator to contain only constant terms or terms with $x$ to powers greater than $2$. $$\frac{1}{1+x}=\frac{1-x}{(1+x)(1-x)}=\frac{1-x}{1-x^2}$$ Now ignore the $x^2$